# Integrate Boilerplate Ignite with React Native

Tags: ubuntu, react-native, boilerplate

I am trying to integrate Boilerplate using react Native on Ubuntu, but somehow I got stuck. 
For web: I cloned a repository from git: 
[Repository](https://github.com/zzz945/react-native-web-boilerplate)

Moved to the clone directory , I have installed npm command, installed MongoDB by downloading it from their site and extract the file. 
I made sure I set the environment in <kbd>.bashrc</kbd> by adding the paths. Run the MongoDB, created a certain js file :

```
export default {
 emailConfig: {
  host: 'smtp.163.com',
  port: '465',
  address: '18504211831@163.com',
  password: '***'
 },
 baseURL: 'http://localhost:8000/'
}
```

And I got stuck there. I even checked the <kbd>package.json</kbd> to make sure it looks like this :

```
serve-start:babel-node –presets react ./server.js
```

But when I run those commands in the terminal, it doesn't show anything:

```
$npm install –save-dev @babel/preset-react
$sudo npm run web-build
```

Did anyone encounter the same stuck?
How can I do the same but for Android?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before running the server commands, there must be checked the versions of the npm and nodejs. 
Check npm version:

```
$npm -v
```

If the version of npm is not the above or latest: 6.2.0

Update the npm running the following command:

```
$npm install -g npm@latest
```

Check nodejs version:

```
$node -v
```

or

```
$nodejs -v
```

If the version of nodejs is not the above or latest: 10.8.0

Update the nodejs running the following commands:

```
$sudo npm install -g n 
$sudo n latest
```

Afterwards you should run :

```
$npm install –save-dev @babel/preset-react
$sudo npm run web-build
```

and you should get the next text (image attached) . I put it in bold the last 2 commands you should run.

Write them with sudo to be sure it won't ask for administrator permission

[Click for image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uWrYI.png)

Comment: It worked , thanks. Apparently I had old versions of those two and that might have been the problem. Do you know what to do for integrating Boilerplate for Android as for web?